# What does quota mean in earth engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have reached my asset quota of 250 GB. So, I thought I could recover some space by deleting some of my assets. Surprisingly, my available storage has not changed even after deleting a bunch of files. I checked from both code editor and command that the deleted files are gone. Is there some sort-of trash folder that I need to empty? Or Does it mean there is no going back after reaching the quota limit.